# Isn't the structure of a potential plaintext of a ciphertext generated by a one-time pad dispositive, cryptanalysis-wise?

Tags: one-time-pad

That is, if I generate every possible result, and analyze the structure against, for example, a dictionary, won't that identify which of the solutions in the domain is most likely the correct one?

I realize the numbers involved, but this does ultimately reduce the problem to a hardware one. If this is not true, then I'm not understanding something correctly about one-time pads.

TIA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No that is not correct, here is the thing, given a ciphertext say `ezcle`, there exists a key such that this would decrypt to `hello`, another key such that this decrypts to `harry`, another key which will decrypt to `frank`, another key which will result in `world`. And every other 5 letter word in the dictionary, and every other 5 letter combination of letters (I'm restricting to letters to make things simple).

Sure there are a lot of outputs that are garbage, but there are a lot of outputs that are not garbage, but every 5 letter word in the dictionary will also appear. Thus, before doing this cryptanalysis, you had a pretty good idea that the ciphertext encrypted a 5 letter english word say. After your cryptanalysis, you have not eliminated a single 5 letter word from the possible plaintexts. Thus you have gained no extra information by doing the cryptanalysis.

Comment: Short and sweet. Excellent answer.